# Move camera on X and Z only

Tags: xna, c#, camera, movement

How would you implement movement on a camera in order to always move it on X and Z coordinates, and if the camera has pitch yaw or roll it still moves only in those coordinates and doesn't fly up?

Comment: How are you moving the camera now, and why can't you, at the end of every frame, just hammer the camera's Y coord?

Answer (score 4):

Anytime you applied a positional change (translation) to the camera, you would flatten that vector out.

Let's say in a non-restricted situation, where the camera could move along the Y-axis, that you have a movement vector like this:

```
Vector3 appliedMovement = new Vector(3, 7, 2);
cameraPosition += appliedMovement;
```

Just remove the Y component.

```
Vector3 appliedMovement = new Vector(3, 7, 2);
appliedMovement.Y = 0.0f;
cameraPosition += appliedMovement;
```

I would recommend making your mutator for your camera class do this, or make a helper function.

**If you have a class for your camera, I would use a mutator:**

```
public Vector3 CameraPosition
{
    get { return value; }
    set 
    {
        if ( isUsingRestrictedVerticalMovement )
        {
            value.Y = 0.0f;
        }

        cameraPosition += value;
    }
}
private Vector3 cameraPosition;
```

**If you don't have a class for your camera, I would write a static utility method to call anytime you moved your camera:**

```
public static class VectorUtils
{
    static public Vector3 FlattenVectorHorizontally( Vector3 vector )
    {      
        vector.Y = 0.0f;
        return vector;
    }
}
```

**Using this helper function with our original code:**

```
Vector3 appliedMovement = VectorUtils.FlattenVectorHorizontally(new Vector(3, 7, 2));
cameraPosition += appliedMovement;
```

**You can make your helper function more efficient by passing by reference**

```
static public void FlattenVectorHorizontally( ref Vector3 vector )
{      
    vector.Y = 0.0f;
}
```

**If you use the version above that passes by reference, you'll need to call the method differently**

```
Vector3 appliedMovement = new Vector(3, 7, 2);
VectorUtils.FlattenVectorHorizontally(appliedMovement);
cameraPosition += appliedMovement;
```

Note that this is exactly what Tetrad's comment in your original question was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

In a first person camera, you can move the camera forward by adding the `camera.direction` values, scaled by `speed * delta` values, to the camera position.  This moves the camera forward in the direction that the camera is facing.  To move the camera forward on just the X and Z planes, you add `camera.direction.x` and `camera.direction.z` to the position.  Create a new vector with `camera.x`, `0f`, and `camera.z`, then normalize it, then scale it by `speed*delta`.

To move the camera left or right, you add/subtract the cross product of your vector with `camera.up` scaled by the `speed*delta` in the same fashion.

Here's the code using libgdx:

```
public void update(float delta) {
    Vector3 xz = new Vector3(camera.direction.x, 0, camera.direction.z).nor();
    if (keys.containsKey(FORWARD)) {
        xz.scl(delta * velocity);
        camera.position.add(xz);
    }
    if (keys.containsKey(BACKWARD)) {
        xz.scl(delta * velocity);
        camera.position.sub(xz);
    }
    if (keys.containsKey(STRAFE_RIGHT)) {
        xz.crs(camera.up).nor().scl(delta * velocity);
        camera.position.add(xz);
    }
    if (keys.containsKey(STRAFE_LEFT)) {
        xz.crs(camera.up).nor().scl(delta * velocity);
        camera.position.sub(xz);
    }
    camera.update(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it using a dummy box, create a dummy box and attach camera as it's child. then whenever you want to move camera, you just have to move the dummy box, if you want to rotate camera left and right you also have to rotate the dummy box but for other axis rotations you will have to rotate camera itself.